# Is only rules will be extends in share eslint config?

Tags: eslint

checkout [eslint#extends](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#extending-configuration-files) section.

> A configuration file can extend the set of enabled rules from base configurations.

so only rules will be extended, and the other options(parserOptions, env, etc.) will be omitted, is that right? is there a way to extend all the eslint config option?

or is the follow stuff a good practice?

```
// .eslintrc.js
var baseConfig = require('another-shareable-eslint-config');
// custom options
baseConfig.root = true;
baseConfig.env = { browser: true };
module.exports = baseConfig;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its going to extend `parserOptions` and `env` as well. Feel free to extends using existing config files or from plugins.